# Why are client SSL certificates filtered out by default in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, ssl, iis-7

Turns out that if the client sends a request signed with his certificate that certificate is ignored by IIS and not passed to managed code. This is because there's `<system.webServer><security><access sslFlags>` property that is set to "None" by default and that means "ignore the certificate".

Changing that value is not allowed by default because `<security>` section is locked and so it must first be unlocked. Clearly someone made an effort to disallow certificates passing to managed code by default.

Why is this the default? Why not just let the certificate through and not touch it?